Complex plane conformal map $g\circ f(A) = B$

Let
$$A:=\{ z \in \Bbb C: |z+1|<2,\ \Re(z)<-1,\ \Im(z) >0\}, \quad f(z) = \frac{3+z}{1-z}$$
Find a conformal map $g$ such that $g\circ f(A) = B$ where
$$B = \{w\in \Bbb C : \Im(w) < \pi \}$$


My approach is the following first I want to understand where $f$ map $A$ than figuring out if there's some map I know that do the work done.
Complex plane's region $A$ is the following

Via $f$ we have

circle $(x+1)^2+y^2=4$ is send to imaginary axe
line $x=-1$ to unit circle
$f(-2+i) = \frac{4+2i}{10}$

Given what's said above I think $f(A)$ has this shape

from here $z\to z^4$ should map my portion to entire circle and then I use what is called in my notes: "Cayley Transform"
$$i\frac{z+1}{z-1}$$
that should map the unit circle in the lower half of the plane. As last I add $\pi i$ and I get my region $B$ as desired... I hope...

Is my approach correct? I'm a little bit dubious since I've read that for $z=0,z^n$ is not a conformal map, but since $0\notin f(A)$ I should be fine. I've tried something quite "visual" so maybe this is a particularly easy exercise to solve this way? Could I have proceeded more algebraically?

$z\to z^4$ does not map the quarter open circle to the entire open circle.

@BobDobbs turn the quarter circle but does not map right?

@BobDobbs actually why do you say that this does not happen? I think It's the correct map

Zero is not in the image.

You found $f(A)$ correctly. Indeed, as you did, we need to check the image of the boundary of $A$:

If $-3<z=x<-1$ real, then $0<3+z<1-z$ and $0<\frac{3+z}{1-z}<1.$

If $z=-1+iy$, $0<y<2$ then $\frac{3+z}{1-z}=\frac{4-y^2+4yi}{4+y^2}$ is on the unit circle and in the first quadrant.

If $z=-1+2e^{i\theta}$, then $\frac{3+z}{1-z}=i\cot\frac{\theta}2$, $\frac\pi 4<\frac\theta 2<\frac\pi 2$, lies on the imaginary axis between $0$ and $i$.


Since $f(0)=3$ lies outside of the unit disk, we conclude that $f(A)$ is bounded and $f(A)=\{z\,:\, |z|<1, \Re z>0, \Im z>0\}$.
Another way to find $g(z)$.
$f_1(z)=z+1$ maps $A=\{z\,:\,|z|<2,\Re z<-1, \Im z>0\}$ to $A_1=\{z\,:\,|z|<2,\Re z<0, \Im z>0\}$ by shifting the region $A$ one unit to the right.
$f_2(z)=\frac z2$ maps $A_1$ to the second quarter of the unit disk $A_2=\{z\,:\,|z|<1,\Re z<0, \Im z>0\}$ by scaling.
$f_3(z)=z^2$ maps $A_2$ to $A_3=\{z\,:\,|z|<1,\Im z<0\}$.
Because, $f_3(re^{i\theta})=r^2e^{i2\theta}$ and $0\leq r^2<1$, $\pi<2\theta<2\pi.$
$f_4(z)=-z$ maps $A_3$ to $A_4=\{z\,:\,|z|<1,\Im z>0\}$, by reflection through the origin which is half-turn.
$f_5(z)=\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ maps $A_4$ to $A_5=\{z\,:\,\Re z>0,\Im z<0\}$.
$f_6(z)=z^2$ maps $A_5$ to $A_6=\{z\,:\,\Im z<0\}$.
$f_7(z)=z+\pi i$ maps $A_6$ to $B=\{z\,:\,\Im z<\pi\}$.
Then,
$$g\circ f(z)=f_7\circ f_6\circ f_5\circ f_4\circ f_3\circ f_2\circ f_1(z)\\=\left(\frac{z^2+2z+5}{3-2z-z^2}\right)^2+\pi i$$
and you can find $g(z)$ from here.

Thank you for your time, I still do not understand why I cannot wrap the quarter circle to the circle with my map. Also $f_2,f_3$ could not be condensed with the map I propose? In my notes that map send unit circle in the lower half plane.

$z\to z^4$ maps your quarter circle onto inside of the unit circle minus [0,1) segment of the real axis.

Is my solution correct? @TurquoiseTilt Maybe someone writes a shorter composition.

I've checked  and seems fine. Instead of trying to wrap directly the circle you wrap the quarter plane. How do you came up with $f_1$?

$+1$ shifts, square makes quarter half, minus is needed for reflection. I think $f_2$ is more interesting. I saw it in a link. Lune link.

I'm back to this problem after a while. I still don't get $f_1$. For me $f(A) = { Re^{i\theta} : 0<R<1, \theta \in (0 ,\pi/2)}$ so If we square this we map $Re^{i\theta}\to R'e^{i\delta}$ such that $0<R'<1, \delta \in (0,\pi)$. From here I agree with your solution, but to me $f_1$ is still mysterious...

Oops sorry I thought we are supposed to find $g\circ f$.

I'm afraid there's something off. How $f_1(z) = z+1$ (which is a translation to the left) send $f(A)$ that is a quarter of the unit disk to $A_1$ that you claim to be a quarter of radius 2 disk? From a certain point I follow your ideas but it's the starting point that I'm quite not getting.

I am finding $g\circ f$ not $g$. Then $g=g\circ f\circ f^{-1}$. Why is the down vote? You upvoted first.

Taking inspiration from some videos online (one and two), I think a valid solution could be

$f_1(z) = z^2$ where $f(A)$ gets mapped to $A_1 = \{re^{i\delta} : r\in (0,1), \delta \in (0,\pi)\}$ (the upper half of the unit disk)
$f_2(z) = \frac{1+z}{1-z}$ and we get $A_2 = \{z \in \Bbb C: \Im(z) >0, \Re(z) >0\}$
$f_3(z) = -z^2$
$f_4(z) = z+i\pi$

composition of this four maps I think it's a solution for the problem.

Thanks for accepting my answer. But, your solution is better. At the begining I did not read your question well. Sorry about that.

@BobDobbs Actually my fault I haven't read carefully your solution I was totally focus on $f(A)$ that I did not understand that you were starting from $A$. Thank you for your patience!
